# Non oem headphones not recognized byphone

Tags: android-10, headphones

I have a blackview bv9900 pro and I have been trying to find a new set of headphones as the oem ones are not comfortable, however all the usb-c headphones and even a usb-c to 3.5 mm adaptor I've bought are not working with the phone.

The operating system doesn't even seem to recognize that anything has been plugged in. I've tried some very basic usb-c headphones from amazon ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07V6FXJ3Q](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07V6FXJ3Q) and
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B097MXHTH9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B097MXHTH9)) and the 3.5mm usb-c adapter ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07VX67Y2M/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VX67Y2M)) none of these have worked, however, if I plug the OEM headset in it works just fine.

I'm wondering if there are any tools I can use to try and get more information from the android system to see if it recongizes that something has been plugged in and if so what it thinks it is that has been plugged in, preferably unrooted, though I don't have issues with going through `adb` but I don't really know where to start with this. Blackview support has been totally useless in helping me figure out whats going on. The phone is currently running Android 10.

Comment: What happens if you connect the original working headphones to a PC? Do they work and what type of device is shown when you connect them to a PC?

Comment: @Robert Interestingly when I plug in the OEM headphones to my computer it complains about the computer not charging. If I plug in the cheap amazon usbc headphones they connect as a sound device and I can see them in device manager under sound devices. I cant find anywhere in device manager where the OEM headphones are listed....